# Sum of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $ V $ be a vector space, and $ W_1,\dots,W_r \subseteq V$ be subspaces of $V$. Now I'm trying to prove $$W_1 + \cdots + W_r = \operatorname{span}(W_1 \cup \cdots \cup W_r).$$

I start with "$ \subseteq $".

Let $ x \in W_1 + \cdots + W_r$ be arbitrary. So we have $x = w_1 + \cdots + w_r$ such that $w_i \in W_i$ for all $i=1,\dots,r$.
From here I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: What's your definition of $span$? Afaik, they differ between sources.

Comment: span(F) means the set of all linear combinations of the vectors of the family $ F:=(v_i)_{i\in I} $.

Comment: Denote $W=W_1\cup ... \cup W_r$. First $\subset$: if $y,z\in W$ then $y+z\in\operatorname{span}W $. By induction, $x=w_1+...+w_r\in W$. Second $\supset$: This the "easy" side.

Answer (score 2):

By the definition of span, we know that every vector on the RHS is of the form $\lambda_1 v_1 +...+ \lambda_r v_r$ for $v_i \in W_i$. Now since the $W_i's$ are subspaces, they are closed under scalar multiplication, hence $\lambda_1 v_1 +...+ \lambda_r v_r \in W_1 +...+ W_r$. Similarly the other inclusion follows.

Answer (score 2):

- $\subset$ :
  Since each of your $w_i \in W_i$, $x$ is a linear combination of elements of $(W_1 \cup ... \cup W_r)$, and therefore of span$(W_1 \cup ... \cup W_r)$.
- $\supset$ :
  Let $x \in$ span$(W_1 \cup ... \cup W_r)$. Then $x = \sum_i \lambda_i y_i$, where $y_i \in W_1 \cup ... \cup W_r$, so that for each $y_i$ there exists $j$ such that $y_i \in W_j$. Since $W_j$ are subspace of V, then $\lambda_i y_i \in W_j$, and so $\sum_i \lambda_i y_i \in  W_1 + ... + W_r$.